# Haskell average coding method

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain why i can't average using this kind of format

```
main = do
    let x = [1,2,3,4]
    print(sum x/length x)
```

I get this error for doing so

```
 No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
     In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(sum x / length x)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (sum x / length x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division operator `/` only works on fractional numbers (this is what the compiler is telling you in the error message).

If you want to use integer division, use the `div` function:

```
print ( sum x `div` length x )
```

But then, of course, your average will also be integer, thus inaccurate.

If you want to work with fractional numbers, you need to convert both `sum x` and `length x` to a fractional type first with `fromIntegral`, then divide:

```
print ( fromIntegral (sum x) / fromIntegral (length x) )
```

Comment: You only need to wrap the length in `fromIntegral`. `sum` gives a non-concrete `Num a` result, it's only `length` that forces its result to `Int`.